# log4net implementation without assemblyinfo.cs

Tags: logging, log4net

I have a WCF service, on which I would like to implement log4net logging. I added the dll, created log4nrt.config file, created Logger.cs file, modified the web.config. Now problem is my application doesnt have AssemblyInfo.cs file.

Is there a way I can implement log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)] somewhere else instead of AssemblyInfo.cs. If so how can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a [global.asax file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2027ewzw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which is a way to add application-wide code to your service (as well as for asp.net projects)

Add your log4net configuration in the class deriving from `HttpApplication` (usually the global.asax comes with an `Application_Start` method ready to be completed with your code)

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to write Log.Info to a different file and Log.Error to a different folder using Log4net?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you managed to create a project without an AssemblyInfo file, but you can add assembly attributes to any class file included in the project:

`Log4NetAssembly.cs`:

```
// Can't use using statements..

[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", 
                                          Watch = true)]
```